# Why were all the C# Shell Extension Examples removed from the All-In-One code framework in April?

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, windows-shell

The samples and the code were described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

And the framework itself is available here:

http://1code.codeplex.com/releases

However, all the shell extension samples were removed in april, with no explanation I can find except this commit message:

http://1code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/63354

Does anybody now why were the samples removed, and do the earlier samples available in previous releases work? (I cannot make them work, but that's probably just me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is crystal clear from the first linked blog post, highlighted in bright yellow:

> In .NET 4, with the ability to have multiple runtimes in process with
>   any other runtime, writing managed shell extensions becomes possible.
>   However, Microsoft has not fully tested all of the scenarios involved
>   with managed shell extensions and has not determined whether it will
>   support managed shell extensions for the long term. Therefore,
>   Microsoft will not support managed shell extensions and recommends
>   against writing them.

When they "recommend against writing them", they cannot also gives examples of how to write them.  For an example of unintended side effects, review this [feedback article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587815/managed-net-4-shell-extension-hangs-explorer-only-in-xp-on-shutdown).

Comment: Thx. Yes, I saw that, but to me it wasn't crystal clear that was the reason for the actual removal of all the samples (not just the icon samples). Also, I wasn't aware that all-in-one code framework was an official MS product, regarding the "recommend against writing them" part (I see now it is MS Community project). I am not using an icon handler, but plan to use the Context Menu extension written in managed code. That is, if there are no problems with it, ergo my question.

Comment: Icon handler or context menu extension, it doesn't make a difference.  Each hooks into the shell extensibility interfaces.  Not so sure I would call the 'all in one framework' a Microsoft product, it was put together by a group in Shanghai that is completely dedicated to forum support.  They got a bit fed-up with answering the same question over and over again and put the common snippets together in one download.  Clearly they got whistled back by Redmond on the shell extension examples, they don't handle phone support.  It is a big company.